# How can I toggle content - one div opens, another closes

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have this toggle script which works perfectly, however what I would like to incorporate into my original toggle code is for it to only allow one `div` to be shown at a time. So when one `div` is open and another link is clicked to open another `div`, the first div should then close.

And how to make when someone visits the page go get already first one opened?

```
// Content Toggle
jQuery(function($){
    // Initial state of toggle (hide)
    $(".slide_toggle_content").hide();

    // Process Toggle click (http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)
    $("h4.slide_toggle").toggle(function(){
        $(this).addClass("clicked");
    }, function () {
        $(this).removeClass("clicked");
    });

    // Toggle animation (http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/)
    $("h4.slide_toggle").click(function() {
        $(this).next(".slide_toggle_content").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Any Ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: post ur html  code too..

Comment: have you considered using http://jqueryui.com/accordion/